# 'stream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Tags: c#, asp.net, stream, cryptography, bouncycastle

I am trying to decrypt a string encrypted by PGP, using BouncyCastle in ASP.NET.

The issue i am getting is on the Stream "privateKeyStream" on properties "ReadTimeout". The IDE says "ReadTimeout = 'privateKeyStream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'"

I tried setting both of the properties to Timeout.Infinite and i have also tried to wrap the MemoryStream in a BufferedStream but nothing seems to work.

Here is the relevant code

```
string privateKeyString = "privatekey";
string passphrase = "passphrase";
byte[] privateKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(privateKeyString);
Stream privateKeyStream = new MemoryStream(privateKeyBytes);
PgpSecretKeyRing secretKeyRing = new PgpSecretKeyRing(privateKeyStream);
```

What am i doing wrong here?